# JAXB XmlElement maxOccurs Issue with Array elements

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jaxb

I have used below getter method level XmlElement annotation for generating xsd from Java class.

**@XmlElement(type=Integer.class, required=true)**

*public int [] getTestArrayInt () { .... }*

**Generated XML element:**

```
<xsd:element name="testArrayInt" type="xsd:int"/>
```

minOccurs's default value is said to be 1. Hence, it is not being displayed here. 
But **maxOccurs="unbounded"** which should be listed for Array elements is missing. Soap UI expects maxOccurs="unbounded" to be present for the array elements. As a result, in Soap UI, this element is not being treated as an array.

When I removed **type=Integer.class** from the annotation, I started getting **maxOccurs="unbounded"** in the XML.

**@XmlElement(required=true)** generated below element:

```
<xsd:element name="testArrayInt" type="xsd:int" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

But I need this ***type*** specially for primitive datatypes. Without ***type*** in annotation, **minOccurs=1** gets missing for elements which are **not required (i.e. required =true is not set)**.

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The issue you describe appears to occur in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) but not the JAXB reference implementation.  MOXy is the default JAXB provider in WebLogic 12.1.1 (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html).  You can track our progress on this issue using the following bug.  If you are a WebLogic customer please enter a bug so that you may receive the appropriate patch.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/395480

**Java Model**

```
package forum13646211;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Root {

    private int[] testArrayInt;

    @XmlElement(type=Integer.class)
    public int [] getTestArrayInt () {
        return testArrayInt;
    }

    public void setTestArrayInt(int[] array) {
        this.testArrayInt = array;
    }

}
```

**Schema (Generated by JAXB RI)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="testArrayInt" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Schema (Generated by EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy))**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="root">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="testArrayInt" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Schema Generation Code**

```
package forum13646211;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The bug is fixed in WLS 12.1.2, which is yet to be released.